# How to pass selected row of Kendo grid data to controller

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a kendo grid with an image near it that will act like a button. When pressed, it will call a controller method. I want to send the selected row data to that method.

**VIEW**

```
<a href="#" id="ic_open" class="tooltip2" title="Abrir">
    <span title="">
        <img class="toolbar-icons" src="../../Images/open.png"/>
    </span>
</a>
...
<div id="datagrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("datagrid_Concessoes")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationDate);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationUser);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 534px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetConcessoes", "MasterData"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

And the **script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.tooltip2').click(function () {

            var id = this.id;

            $.get('@Url.Content("GetPartialView")',
            { "id": id },
            function (data) {
                $('#div-for-partial').html(data);
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

This script sends the link's id (*ic_open*) to the controller successfully. I want to send the selected row data, via this same function or some other (doesn't matter), to the controller so I can manipulate that info.

## EDIT

**Controller method**

```
public ActionResult GetPartialView(string id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case "":
            return PartialView("_Concessoes");
        case "tab1":
            return PartialView("_Concessoes");
        case "tab2":
            return PartialView("_AutoEstradas");
        case "ic_open":
            return PartialView("_NovaConcessao");

    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Script should be as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.tooltip2').click(function () {

            var id = this.id;

            var concessoesGrid = $("#datagrid_Concessoes").data("kendoGrid");
            var row = concessoesGrid.select();    

            $.get('@Url.Content("GetPartialView")',
            { "id": id, "modelData":row },
            function (data) {
                $('#div-for-partial').html(data);
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Now there will be change on your controller side also:

```
   public ActionResult GetPartialView(string id, ModelClass modelData)
    {

       //here you can access the modelData Object which will have the value of Selcted row of Grid
        switch (id)
        {
            case "":
                return PartialView("_Concessoes");
            case "tab1":
                return PartialView("_Concessoes");
            case "tab2":
                return PartialView("_AutoEstradas");
            case "ic_open":
                return PartialView("_NovaConcessao");

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

NOTE: if you want to pass multiple selected grid records to controller then you will need to change the controller argument to accept List of objects.

Comment: That brings the javascript error `the argument is not optional`. I believe I tried that before

Comment: Can you try changing the controller argument to **IEnumerable<ModelClass> modelData**

Comment: @chiapa as **Tough Coder** mentioned you can use **JSON.stringify(row)** when passing the data to the Action of Cotroller.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It wasn't your solution that worked exactly but some tips helped me reach the goal. I've added `.Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))` to the grid definition and wrote a js function: `function onChange() { var code = this.dataItem(this.select()).Code; $.get('@Url.Content("getConcessionCode")', { "code": code });}` This way I can pass the selected row code and from there use the related data.

Answer (score 1):

I am using KendoJS but I believe this would also work on your side too:

```
var grid = $("yourgrid's id or class");
var selectedRow;
grid.change = function()
{
   grid.select().each(function () {
         var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
          selectedRow = dataItem;
   });
}
```

I also found [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/overview) for Kendo ASP.NET MVC:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("grid")
      .Events(e => e
          .DataBound(@<text>
              function() {
                  //Handle the dataBound event inline
              }
          </text>)
          .Change(@<text>
              var selectedRow;
              function() {
                       var grid = this;
                        grid.select().each(function () {
                        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
                        selectedRow = dataItem;                          
                    });
              }
          </text>)
      )
)
```

After getting the selected row, the rest is easy. Just send the value you want into your hidden value element on your cshtml page or just call the ajax method for your controller right over on your JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm trying to catch that `dataItem` in the controller but it comes as null. I don't even know what type should it be, I've tried `object`, `string` and `List<string>`.

Comment: @chiapa you can use JSON.stringify(dataItem) and then send it to your controller as one class. ASP.NET MVC has an automatic binder for JSON objects if the property name matches with your C# class.